Are there any ring homomorphisms from extension field to base field?
Let $L \supset K$ be a proper field extension. I want to show there are no ring homomorphisms $\phi: L \to K$.
My proof
Let $\tilde{L}=\phi(L)$ be the image of $L$ by $\phi$, and we endow a $L$ vector space structure on it by $l\cdot x:=\phi(l)x\ (l \in L, x\in \tilde{L}$).
First $\phi$ induces a ring isomorphism $L\cong \tilde{L}$. Then since $$\phi(ly)=\phi(l)\phi(y)=l\cdot \phi(y)\ (l \in L, y\in L),$$
it is also an isomorphism of $L$ vector space.
So $L\supset\tilde{L}$ and $\dim_L L=1=\dim_L \tilde{L}<\infty$, it follows that $L=\tilde{L}$. So $L=K$ and this is contradiction.
Question
Is my attempt above correct? And does it have easier proof?

This is confusing. $L = \mathbb{Q}(x_0, x_1, x_2, \cdots)$ is a proper field extension of $K = \mathbb{Q}(x_1, x_2, \cdots)$. But they are even isomorphic. Would that count as a counterexample for your purpose?

It's certainly counterexample but I don't know where is my mistake...

I’m not completely sure I understand what your intended argument is, but it seems to me you’ve ignored that the two $L$-vector space structures, one on $L$ and one on $\tilde{L}$, are not compatible. To put it another way, the inclusion $\tilde{L} \subset L$ is only of sets, not of $L$-vector spaces, as for the latter you would need $l \cdot x = lx$ for $l \in L$ and $x \in \tilde{L}$, which is not true since the former is actually $\phi(l)x$.

This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

@MartinBrandenburg I posted these as comments precisely because I don’t think they count as a full answer, given that I’m not even sure if I understand the OP’s wrong attempt at the question and thus not sure if my analysis of the OP’s mistakes in their attempt makes sense. If the OP confirms that I have correctly understood their attempt and that I have cleared up their confusion, I will re-post these as an answer.

I see, certainly there's no reason $\tilde{L}$ is a sub $L$ vector space of $L$... Thank you!
